# Xamarin.forms : BoxView flickers while scrolling

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use a BoxView with HeightRequest="0.5" as a separator between some other elements. 
The separator and the rest are inside a StackLayout that is inside a vertical ScrollView.

Everything looks good but while scrolling the height of my BoxView changes. So while scrolling the BoxViews have a flickering effect.
 I have also tried to use Label instead but if flickers as well.

Have you any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or on a device?

Comment: Some devices are unable to show 0.5 dpi. The same happens when you change its  Height to 1?

Comment: We are facing the same issue and have no solution for this yet.. Could you solve it in the meantime? Found this issue, which seems to be related: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8648